# I am making my first ml model. I cannot understand what this line of code is doing?

Tags: pandas, numpy, dictionary, tensorflow

```
features = {key:np.array(value) for key,value in dict(features).items()}
```

What is value? Why is features put as a parameter for dict constructor?

Comment: I think you have to check doc.

Answer (score 1):

`features = {key:np.array(value) for key,value in dict(features).items()}` is a basic comprehension. There are list-comprehensions and dict -comprehensions ( maybe even more).See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html for further details.  Long story short you have a `for-loop` run over an `iterator` and directly use the arguments to construct a `list` / `dict` in your case

```
{key:np.array(value) for key,value in dict(features).items()}
```

`{key:np.array(value) ...`  is the usual dict-creation syntax
`for key,value in dict(features).items()` a simple for loop over a dictionary of features.

Together they create a new `dict` for every `key` of the `dict(features).items()` with the corresponding `np.array(value)` for every value of `dict(features).items()`